# Python + dataframe : AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I am trying to write a function to do some text processing on the specified columns (description, event_name) of a Pandas dataframe.
I wrote this code:

```
#removal of unreadable chars, unwanted spaces, words of at most length two from 'description' column and lowercase the 'description' column

def data_preprocessing(source):

    return source.replace('[^A-Za-z]',' ')
    #data['description'] = data['description'].str.replace('\W+',' ')
    return source.lower()
    return source.replace("\s\s+" , " ")
    return source.replace('\s+[a-z]{1,2}(?!\S)',' ')
    return source.replace("\s\s+" , " ")

data['description'] = data['description'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
data['event_name'] = data['event_name'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
```

It is giving the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-cb5ec147833f> in <module>()
----> 1 data['description'] = data['description'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
      2 data['event_name'] = data['event_name'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
      3 
      4 #df['words']=df['words'].apply(lambda row: eliminate_space(row))
      5 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2549             else:
   2550                 values = self.asobject
-> 2551                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2552 
   2553         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-94-cb5ec147833f> in <lambda>(row)
----> 1 data['description'] = data['description'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
      2 data['event_name'] = data['event_name'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
      data['description'] = data['description'].str.replace('\W+',' ')    
<ipython-input-93-fdfec5f52a06> in data_preprocessing(source)
      3 def data_preprocessing(source):
      4 
----> 5     return source.replace('[^A-Za-z]',' ')
      6     #data['description'] = data['description'].str.replace('\W+',' ')
      7     source = source.lower()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

If I write the code in following way, without function, it works perfectly:

```
data['description'] = data['description'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z]',' ')
```

Comment: Try `data['description'] = data['description'].astype(str).apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to fix:

**First**, when you `apply` a lambda function to a pandas Series, the lambda function is applied to each *element* of the Series. What I think you need is to apply your function to the entire Series in a vectorized manner.

**Second**, your function has multiple return statements. As a result, only the first statement, `return source.replace('[^A-Za-z]',' ')`, will ever run. What you need to do is make your preprocessing changes on the variable `source` inside your function, and finally return the modified `source` (or an intermediate variable) at the very end.

To rewrite your function to operate on an entire pandas Series, replace every occurrence of `source.` with `source.str.`. The new function definition:

```
def data_preprocessing(source):
    source = source.str.replace('[^A-Za-z]',' ')
    #data['description'] = data['description'].str.replace('\W+',' ')
    source = source.str.lower()
    source = source.str.replace("\s\s+" , " ")
    source = source.str.replace('\s+[a-z]{1,2}(?!\S)',' ')
    source = source.str.replace("\s\s+" , " ")
    return source
```

Then, instead of this:

```
data['description'] = data['description'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
data['event_name'] = data['event_name'].apply(lambda row: data_preprocessing(row))
```

Try this:

```
data['description'] = data_preprocessing(data['description'])
data['event_name'] = data_preprocessing(data['event_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks Man. Your answer is perfect. :)